# python list different way than googles solution

Tags: python

I am working on the exercises for python from Google and I can't figure out why I am not getting the correct answer for a list problem. I saw the solution and they did it differently then me but I think the way I did it should work also.

```
# B. front_x
# Given a list of strings, return a list with the strings
# in sorted order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first.
# e.g. ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] yields
# ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
# Hint: this can be done by making 2 lists and sorting each of them
# before combining them.
def front_x(words):
  # +++your code here+++
  list = []
  xlist = []
  for word in words:
    list.append(word)
  list.sort()
  for s in list:
    if s.startswith('x'):
      xlist.append(s)
      list.remove(s)
  return xlist+list
```

The call is:

```
front_x(['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'])
```

I get: 
['xaa', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'xzz']
when the answer should be: 
['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'b
bb', 'ccc']

I've don't understand why my solution does not work

Thank you.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, don't use `list` as a variable name.  Generally you don't want to use the name of any python built-in as a variable name as then you lose access to that built-in in your namespace.

Comment: The google exercises are good practice.  Good luck!  Eventually things like `sorted(words, key=lambda word: (not word.startswith("x"), word))` will start to seem natural. :^)

Comment: @DSM -- Very natural indeed.  (I posted the same thing on the solution by stleary without seeing your comment here -- It must be the natural way to do this :).

Comment: @mgilson: one obvious way! :^)

Comment: @DSM -- That's what I was thinking.  How very Zen of us ... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't modify a list while iterating over it.  See [the `for` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

```
  for s in list:
    if s.startswith('x'):
      xlist.append(s)
      list.remove(s)    # this line causes the bug
```

Comment: @mgilson I did not think I needed to sort xlist because I am pulling it out in order of list which is already sorted.

Comment: @ecatmur thank you, it seems to partially work which I think is strange.

Comment: You should probably add that the typical way to mutate a list while iterating over it is to use a slice to make a copy :  `for s in list[:]: ...` (although mutating a list while iterating over it should *rarely* be necessary).

Comment: @ecatmur:  +0.  I think that should be worded differently.  You *can* modify a list while iterating it, but you usually *shouldn't*.  That line isn't illegal so much as it is incorrect for the goal at hand.

Comment: Although this is the source of OP's bug, I don't agree that it's "illegal" to do this; merely a bad idea most of the time. See [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) - the documentation confirms that mixing mutation and iteration can lead to bugs, but does not explicitly forbid it.

Comment: If you're going to be deleting things from a list, iterate it in reverse order to prevent these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def front_x(words):
    lst = []
    xlst = []
    for word in words:
        if word.startswith('x'):
            xlst.append(word)
        else:
            lst.append(word)
    return sorted(xlst)+sorted(lst)


>>> front_x(['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'])
['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: or `return sorted(words, key = lambda x: (not x.startswith('x') , x) )` -- but the question was more about why the OP's code didn't work.

Comment: I did basically the same thing to fix it, i did not know I couldn't modify the list while iterating over it: